# continue is only allowed inside a loop

Tags: swift

Is this a bug in Swift where any code placed inside an autoreleasepool thinks that it's  not inside the loop? Is there a workaround for this rather then making a messy code by separating my code into multiple autorelease pools?

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    autoreleasepool {
        // Lots of allocation and lots of logic

        continue // Need to continue to the next loop

        // Lots of allocation and lots of logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The argument of `autoreleasepool` is a closure, so you can just *early return*
from the closure:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    autoreleasepool {
        // Lots of allocation and lots of logic

        if someCondition { return } // Need to continue to the next loop

        // Lots of allocation and lots of logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that last continue was a typo in the question, it wasn't part of my code

Comment: @aryaxt: OK, so I'll remove that part from the answer.